# How to use base64 string from database to display an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

How can I use base64 string from database to display an image? I can't see any function to convert this by using jQuery DataTables.

```
oTableImage = $('#tbl_image').DataTable({
        "processing": true,            
        "destroy": true,
        "paging":false,
        "bFilter": false,
        // "scrollY": "200px",
        "ajax":{
            "type":"POST",
            dataType: "json",   
            "url":"{{ URL::to('ajax/per-seller-image') }}",
            "data":function(d){
                d.rtd_id =rtd;
            }
        },

        "columns":[
            {data: 'start_image', name: 'start_image'}
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Can I ask what are using on the server side? Using `data:image` might not be the way to go. It's likely more advisable to make a handler on your server to serve the binary content of the image instead of returning base64 data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show a base64 encoded image in HTML like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,xxxxxxxxxxBASE64_HASHxxxxxxxx===">
```

And then render the `<img>` tag in DataTable:

```
"columns": [
    {
        "render": function (data, type, row) {
            return '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + row.start_image + '">';
        }
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Base64 data will be automatically rendered by browser itself. You don't have to convert.